# hide menu and footer for some .phtml pages

Tags: menu, footer

we wanted to hide menu and footer for some pages[.phhtml]

this is code for the following page : http://pastebin.com/NghF3bC1

http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/marketplace/

what code we have to use to restrict menu and footer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="marketplace">
                <label>Marketplace</label>
                <url>marketplace</url>
                <title>Marketplace</title>
                <prepare>true</prepare>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>marketplace/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>marketplace/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>marketplace/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>

    <marketplace_index_toplinkmarketplace>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <!--<Urvashi add this code>-->
            <reference name="header">
                <block type="page/header" name="header">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/seller.phtml</template></action> 
                </block> 
            </reference>
        <!--Urvashi Up to here >-->

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/marketplace" name="marketplace" template="marketplace/marketplace.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_index_toplinkmarketplace>
    <marketplace_account_becomepartner>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/becomepartner" name="marketplace_becomepartner" template="marketplace/becomepartner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_becomepartner>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="core/template" name="wk-block" template="marketplace/wk_block.phtml" before="-"></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="customer_conf" template="marketplace/confpartner.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
    <customer_account>
         <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplacenavigation" template="marketplace/navigation.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    <marketplace_account_editaccount>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="edit_myprofile" template="marketplace/edit_myprofile.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_editaccount>
    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_newproduct>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/newproduct" name="new_product" template="marketplace/newproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_newproduct>

   <marketplace_account_configurableproduct>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>     
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script></action>     
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_addproduct" template="marketplace/newconfigurableproduct.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_configurableproduct>

    <marketplace_account_configurableassociate>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/associate" name="marketplace_account_configurableassociate" template="marketplace/configurableassociate.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_configurableassociate>

    <marketplace_account_configurableproductattr>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/products" name="marketplace_account_configurableproductattr" template="marketplace/configurableproductattr.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_configurableproductattr>
    <marketplace_account_newattribute>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>             
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/products" name="marketplace_account_newattribute" template="marketplace/newattribute.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_newattribute>
    <marketplace_account_simpleproduct>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_addproduct" template="marketplace/simpleproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_simpleproduct>
    <marketplace_account_downloadableproduct>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_addproduct" template="marketplace/downloadableproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_downloadableproduct>
    <marketplace_account_virtualproduct>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_addproduct" template="marketplace/virtualproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_virtualproduct>
    <marketplace_account_productlist>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/marketplace" name="marketplace_myproductslist" template="marketplace/myproductlist.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_productlist>
    <marketplace_account_simpleproductedit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_editproducts" template="marketplace/editsimpleproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_simpleproductedit>
    <marketplace_account_downloadableproductedit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_editproducts" template="marketplace/editdownloadableproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_downloadableproductedit>
    <marketplace_account_virtualproductedit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_editproducts" template="marketplace/editvirtualproduct.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_virtualproductedit>
    <marketplace_account_configurableproductedit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>     
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>marketplace/js/nicEdit-latest.js</script></action>     
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_editproducts" template="marketplace/editconfigurableproduct.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_configurableproductedit>
    <marketplace_account_dashboard>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/products" name="marketplace_dashboard" template="marketplace/mydashboard.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_dashboard>
    <marketplace_account_orderhistory>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/products" name="marketplace_myorderhistory" template="marketplace/myorderhistory.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_account_orderhistory>

    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_vieworder>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="Sales/Order_Item_Renderer_Default" name="marketplace_view_order" template="marketplace/vieworder.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_vieworder>

    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_printorder>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="Sales/Order_Item_Renderer_Default" name="marketplace_view_order" template="marketplace/printorder.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_printorder>

    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_viewtransdetails>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="marketplace_view_transaction" template="marketplace/viewtransdetails.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_viewtransdetails>

    <marketplace_seller_profile>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/profile" name="marketplace" template="marketplace/profile.phtml" />
            <block type="marketplace/profile" name="product_bestsell_block" template="marketplace/product_bestsell_block.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.newsletter"></remove>
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout"></remove>
            <block type="marketplace/profile" name="profile_store_left_sidebar" template="marketplace/profile_store_left_sidebar.phtml" />
            <block type="marketplace/profile" name="partner_profile_right" template="marketplace/profile_right_sidebar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_seller_profile>
    <marketplace_seller_collection>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.newsletter"></remove>
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout"></remove>
            <block type="marketplace/sellercategory" name="partner_category" template="marketplace/sellercategory.phtml" before="-" />
            <block type="marketplace/sellercategory" name="collection-left" template="marketplace/collectionleft.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/collection" name="marketplace_collection8" template="marketplace/collectionview.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_seller_collection>
    <marketplace_seller_location>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="location_form" template="marketplace/location.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="left.newsletter"></remove>
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout"></remove>
            <block type="marketplace/location" name="profile_store_left_sidebar" template="marketplace/profile_store_left_sidebar.phtml" />
            <block type="marketplace/location" name="partner_profile_right" template="marketplace/profile_right_sidebar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_seller_location>
    <marketplace_seller_feedback>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/wk_block.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="marketplace/feedback" name="review_form" template="marketplace/reviewform.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="marketplace/feedback" name="partner_profile_right" before="-" template="marketplace/profile_right_sidebar.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </marketplace_seller_feedback>


    <marketplace_transaction_info>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>marketplace/css/style.css</stylesheet></action>             
        </reference>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="content">    
            <block type="marketplace/transactions" name="marketplace_transaction" template="marketplace/transactions.phtml" />  
        </reference>
    </marketplace_transaction_info>


</layout>
```

Comment: use this code in your local.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <marketplace-index-index>
    <remove name="header" />
  </marketplace-index-index>
</layout>

Comment: okay, i i will try.....

Comment: i tried your code , but after this : http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/errors/report.php?id=1414056695678&skin=default

Comment: use _ instead of -

Comment: @BernhardPrange i used _ ,  it did't worked....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use xml to hide the menu and footer

```
 <marketplace_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topMenu</alias></action>
    </reference>
 </marketplace_index_index>
```

Comment: where  i have to place the following code  i tried in local.xml file, but it did't work.....

Comment: your module xml in layout folder add it there. find this <marketplace_index_index> tag and add it there

Comment: it worked fine for menu , but footer is still there : http://pastebin.com/YsfG8FdH

Comment: Use action tag for footer too and replace topmenu to footer that will work or remove reference tag and check

Comment: <marketplace_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
         <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topMenu</alias></action>
    </reference>
 <reference name="footer">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>footer</alias></action>
    </reference>
 </marketplace_index_index>

Comment: i tried above code , but did't work.....

Comment: <marketplace_index_index>
             <remove name="footer"/>
     <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topMenu</alias></action>
    </reference>

 </marketplace_index_index> add it like that.and check

Comment: footer is a static block, will that work ? http://hotwheelstoys.in/mobileapp2/marketplace/

Comment: It don't matter if it is inside the footr tag

Comment: do you want to check any other file, so i i will post the code here....

Comment: Paste it let me look at that

Comment: footer is working fine, thanks but i need to hide some static blocks, please help

Comment: Give me block name and where they are uding

Comment: block name : EM0113 Best Friends Footer Follow Us
block id : em0113_footer_follow_us

Comment: is this name of block in xml too?

Comment: yes, same name in xml too

Comment: try this if it is in this page
<marketplace_index_index>
<reference name="footer">
<remove name="em0113_footer_follow_us"/>
</reference>
</marketplace_index_index>

Comment: i did't got, can you please explain

Comment: which page you want to remove that block?

Comment: same page as above....

Comment: try that code..

Comment: i tried this : <reference name="EM0113 Best Friends Footer Follow Us">
                  <action method="unsetChild"><alias>EM0113 Best Friends     Footer Follow Us</alias></action>
    </reference> but did't worked

Comment: <reference name="footer"> <action method="unsetChild"><alias>em0113_footer_follow_us</alias></action> </reference>

use that

Comment: not working.....

Comment: if you remove the footer how is this block showing?

Comment: this is not related to footer block, before i mis understood. this is some other block in site

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ukS0LaA6 where i have to add your code in this file to hide menu and footer

Comment: pastebin link showing 404. so kindly paste somewhere else..

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: which page you want to remove it

Comment: i want to remove on all pages of this module......

Comment: paste this code in all pages of this extension 

<reference name="root">
        <remove name="footer"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topMenu</alias></action>
    </reference>

Comment: we have module.xml file, i placed the code.but its not working.

can you please tell below which line i have to add the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30993/discussion-between-qaisar-satti-and-baby-in-magento-2).

Answer (score 2):

```
<reference name="root">
<remove name="head"/>
<remove name="header"/>
<remove name="footer"/>
<remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</reference>
```

Put this in your Update layout xml in CMS Page.

Comment: i need for .phtml files in under app/design/ part , not for cms pages